# Javascript Function innerHTML with no style

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have this base code:

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div id="ingredientadd" class="col">
    <label for="ingredient">Ingredient</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="ingredient" name="ingredient">
  </div>
  <div id="quantityadd" class="col">
    <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="quantity" name="quantity">
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-2 mb-4" onclick="myFunction()">New ingredient</button>
```

which looks like this:
[image]
Note that I am using **Boostrap**. However, when I want to add 2 more input fields with this JS code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ingredient = document.createElement("input");
  ingredient.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="ingredient" name="ingredient">';
  document.getElementById("ingredientadd").appendChild(ingredient);

  var quantity = document.createElement("input");
  quantity.innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="quantity" name="quantity">';
  document.getElementById("quantityadd").appendChild(quantity)
}
```

The input fields stack like this:
[image]
Without any style.

The second problem is that when I press the *New ingredient* button, the entire form submits.
It is a Flask website. Currently to add the new fields I have a second button really down in the page:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In button you are missing

> type="button"

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div id="ingredientadd" class="col">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="ingredient">Ingredient</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="ingredient" name="ingredient">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="quantityadd" class="col">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="quantity" name="quantity">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-2 mb-4" onclick="myFunction()">New ingredient</button>
```

js code

```
  function myFunction() {
   var ingredient = document.createElement("div");
   ingredient.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label 
   for="ingredient">Ingredient</label><input type="text" class="form-control form- 
   control-sm" id="ingredient" name="ingredient"></div>';
   document.getElementById("ingredientadd").appendChild(ingredient);

   var quantity = document.createElement("div");
   quantity.innerHTML = '<div class="form-group"><label 
   for="quantity">Quantity</label><input type="text" class="form-control form-control- 
    sm" id="quantity" name="quantity"></div>';
   document.getElementById("quantityadd").appendChild(quantity)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

- By **default** a button ***type*** is **`"submit"`**  so always use `<button type="button">` otherwise a wrapping form will trigger *submit*.
- **Don't use inline `on*=""` attribute** handlers, same as you (hopefully) don't use inline `style=""` attributes - Use [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead
- `<input>` is in the family of [***Void elements***](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements), has no closing tag and does not accepts `innerHTML` operations.
- Don't use ID for repeated fields  - **ID is unique!**
- Use `name="quantity[]"` with `[]` in order to collect those fields values with the same ***name*** as array

```js
// Helpers
const EL = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelector(sel);
const ELS = (sel, EL) => (EL || document).querySelectorAll(sel);
const ELNew = (sel, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(sel), prop || {});
const ELAttr = (EL, attr) => Object.entries(attr).forEach(([p, v]) => EL.setAttribute(p, v));

// Form fields
function addFormFields() {

  const form_row = ELNew("div", {
    className: "form-row"
  });
  
  const label_ingredient = ELNew("label", {
    innerHTML: "<span>Ingredient</span>"
  });
  
  const label_quantity = ELNew("label", {
    innerHTML: "<span>Quantity</span>"
  });
  
  const input_ingredient = ELNew("input", {
    className: "form-control form-control-sm",
    type: "text",
    name: "ingredient[]",
  });
  
  const input_quantity = ELNew("input", {
    className: "form-control form-control-sm",
    type: "text",
    name: "quantity[]",
  });
  
  label_ingredient.append(input_ingredient)
  label_quantity.append(input_quantity);
  form_row.append(label_ingredient, label_quantity);
  EL("#form").append(form_row)
}

// Add fields on click
EL("#new-ingredient").addEventListener("click", addFormFields);
// Add fields on page init
addFormFields();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<form class="form" id="form"></form>

<button id="new-ingredient" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-2 mb-4">New ingredient</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

something simple

```
    <div class="form-row">
        <div id="ingredientadd" class="col">
            <label for="ingredient">Ingredient</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="ingredient" name="ingredient">
        </div>

        <div id="quantityadd" class="col">
            <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="quantity" name="quantity">
        </div>
      </div>

    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-2 mb-4" onclick="myFunction()">New ingredient</button>
```

javascript

```
    function myFunction() {
    var $wrapper = document.querySelector('#ingredientadd'),
        // get actual content
        HTMLTemp = $wrapper.innerHTML,
        //new input that will be inserted
        HTMLNew = '<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="ingredient" name="ingredient">';
    HTMLTemp = HTMLTemp + HTMLNew
     // insert new input in DOM with new content
    $wrapper.innerHTML = HTMLTemp;

    var $wrappertwo = document.querySelector('#quantityadd'),
        // get actual content
        HTMLTemptwo = $wrappertwo.innerHTML,
        //new input that will be inserted
        HTMLNewtwo = ' <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="quantity" name="quantity">';
    HTMLTemptwo = HTMLTemptwo + HTMLNewtwo
    // insert new input in DOM with new content
    $wrappertwo.innerHTML = HTMLTemptwo;
}
```